# How to retrieve multiple values from multiple checkboxes without page refresh

Tags: javascript, python, json, flask

index.html contains:

```
<div class="result">{{ result|safe }}</div>
```

I have a list of inputs for 4 separate checkboxes that looks like this:

```
    <ul class="filterSection">
    <li>
        <strong>Show:</strong>
        <input checked="true" type="checkbox" name="check" value="value1"/>
        <label>First</label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input checked="true" type="checkbox" name="check" value="value2"/>
        <label>Second</label>
    </li>

     <li>
        <input checked="true" type="checkbox" name="check" value="value3"/>
        <label>Third</label>
    </li>
     <li>
        <input checked="true" type="checkbox" name="check" value="value4"/>
        <label>Fourth</label>
    </li>
    </ul>
```

This is the part I need help with. In javascript, I need to get these 4 values every time a checkbox is checked or unchecked and send all 4 values to server without page refresh. Then I will do something to data based upon these 4 values, and then send new data back. I need to retrieve value1, value2, value3, value4 in flask and know if they are checked/unchecked. Here's what I attempted so far:

```
$(function() {
    $.getJSON('/_filter', {
        b: $('input[name="check"]').val(),
      }, function(data) {
        $('.result').html(data.result)
    return false;
    });
    });
```

Lastly, in my flask app, I have:

```
@app.route('/_filter')
def filter_results():
    value = request.args.get('b') ## I don't know how to get all 4 values
    ##compare the 4 values  
    ##update index page with newdata based upon the values of the checkboxes            
    return jsonify(result=newdata)
```

Comment: None of which explain how to handle within flask environment which is specific to my question.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I have a lot of questions. So confused, didn't know where to start. Links are helping though.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/Lg84r6en/ - you can even use `JSON.stringify(res)`

Comment: I have issues with JSFiddle. Here is the code `$(function() {
  $("[name=type]").on("click", function() {
    var res = {};
    var vals = $("[name=" + this.name + "]").each(function() {
      res[this.value] = this.checked;
    }).get();
    console.log(JSON.stringify(res))
  });
});`

Answer (score 0):

You can use  onclick event with checkbox.In onclick event fire a function in which you can store the value of associated checkbox in some array to get the values of all checkboxes.

Comment: Thanks for all the links @mplungjan I'm going to sort through them all and see if I can get further. Can you please give me an example of an onclick event with checkbox? I'm playing with this http://jsfiddle.net/dp2g79no/ , but haven't got the onclick event to work.